# password reading

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to write an algorithm that reads keyboard stream until it gets a correct password.

like if the password is ababac,
and the input is abababa, it means so far it read ababa and now it waits for a c to get unlocked, if an f comes in instead of a c, then it restarts its process.

it easily can be done in O(n^2), but my teacher want us to do it in O(n) W.C, can it get done in this complexity?!

Comment: Do you mean it reads the first octets if they are `ababa` and then just drop every octet read until it's a `c` ? How is that complex ? just basically `read` and then drop your octets and keep a trace on which char you are in your password string... no?

Comment: nope, i edited the question to clearify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build an [automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automaton) for it.

For this approach - you can use [Aho–Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) - create the data automaton for the string, and start feeding it with the input text, until you reach its end [don't accept] or you reached an accepting state in the automaton.

Aho-Corasick is linear in the pattern [password] and input size, so you get `O(m+n)`

Comment: this is not as trivial as you put it is it?... generalized algorithm for automating all possible pw's is way more then my teacher can require...

Comment: @OfekRon: (1) the question is `can it get done in this complexity?!` - it can, with Aho–Corasick (2) I agree it is not that simple, I doubt there is trivial linear solution for it [if there was, I don't think there were so many algorithms for substring matchings]. (3) If your teacher expects "simple" - maybe he/she were wrong about the complexity?

Comment: @OfekRon: One more thing - I might have misunderstood the question - this solution assumes you are looking for a substring which is the password. Maybe you need a [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence)? for example, "ac" is a subsequence of "abc" if it is the case - the solution is fairly easier and includes a pointer to each string and a single loop. The example you provided in the question does not clarify which one you are looking for.

Comment: @amit according to the comment on NPToita's answer OP needs substring

Answer (score 5):

I think online version of [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) will do the job. You would have to store and calculate index array (additional O(n) memory in case of circular array implementation), though.

Comment: i doubt it would bring you to O(n) in an online version... try to pseudocode it and see...

Comment: Online algorithm takes O(PASSWORD_SIZE) for preprocessing and O(INPUT_SIZE) for the rest of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach would be to store the input in a circular `char` buffer and use a custom `strcmp()` to check whether it contains the password. This method is in O(n).

Comment: yes this method is O(n), but u activating it O(n) times, which brings you to O(n^2)...

Comment: i am familiar with that, tho its not really helpfull in this case, because every password requires a diffrent automate, there is no general automate for passwords...

Comment: When you mentioned FSM I thought of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster. Not as helpful, true, but much funnier than Finite State Machines.

Comment: Alex: You have a twisted sense of fun  ;)

Answer (score 0):

this is the closest i got to Linear time...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node_t {
    char c;
    struct node_t * next;
    struct node_t * prev;
} node;


void pop();
void printIT(node *p);
void fixList();
char addToList(char c);
long silence_keyboard(char pw[] ,int size);

char pw[256];
node *head = NULL;
node *tail = NULL;
int i = 0 , listSize = 0;



void main(void)
 {  
    printf("Set PW:");
    scanf("%s",pw);
    printf("Enter PW (silence_keyboard is activated):\n");
    printf("\npw was entered.",silence_keyboard(pw,strlen(pw)));
 } 


long silence_keyboard(char pw[] ,int size) {
    while (i<size) {
        for (; i<size && addToList(getche())==pw[i] ; i++);
        if (i<size) fixList();
    }
    return 0;
}

char addToList(char c) {
    node *temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (!temp) exit(1);
    temp->c=c;
    temp->next=NULL;
    temp->prev=tail;
    if (!tail) head=temp;
    else tail->next=temp;
    tail=temp;
    listSize++;
    return c;
}

void fixList() {
    node *p=tail;
    int j;
    while (1) {
        for ( ; i>=0 && pw[i]!=tail->c ; i--) {
            pop();
            printf("\nso far:");
            printIT(head);
            printf("    pw:%s\n",pw);
        }
        for ( p=tail,j=i ; j>=0 && pw[j]==p->c ; j-- , p=p->prev );
        if (j<0) break;
        else {
            pop();
            printf("\nso far:");
            printIT(head);
            printf("    pw:%s\n",pw);
            i--;
        }
    }
    i=listSize; 
}

void printIT(node *p) {
    if (p) {
        printf("%c",p->c);
        printIT(p->next);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

}

void pop() {
    node *p=head;
    if (!head) return;
    if (head==tail) tail=NULL;
    head=head->next;
    free(p);
    listSize--;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
password = "ababac"
index = 0
while index < password.length
{
  read character into x
  if( x == password[index])
    index++;
}

cout << "congrads!!! you got the password!!";
```

Comment: The OP aims to detect keywords in a stream of characters. You just meshed together `strcmp()` and I/O.

Comment: Based on OP question "input is abababa, it reads "ababa" and waits for c to get unlocked" so "ababafffc" would trigger the password-check and this pseudo-pseudocode is correct.

Comment: OK i see where I misunderstood. The correct version would be "The input is 'zxczababa'." It reads the last ababa and not the first ababa inside abababa...

Comment: why the many downvotes? this is a perfectly valid description of the algorithm before Ofek clarified his question; it's trivial to fix for the desired outcome -- just append `else index = 0` to the loop's body...

Comment: @Christoph It ["fixed" algorithm] will fail for `password=="aac"` and `input=="aaac"`

Comment: @amit: *headdesk* - you're right; note to self: do not check stackoverflow before ingesting the appropriate amount of caffeine

Comment: The above is a psuedo code not that actual code. and the string "ababac" is and example of the password that the OP could use, and of course password is a variable.  And in the original post the OP said to wait for the next correct keyword instead of resetting the check if a keyword doesn't match up with the password string.